# add animate.css classes then remove the element with remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add some css classes on my label/checkbox tick, then remove the classes and then remove the item once it's been checked. Though I'm struggling and only managing to do one or the other.

```
$(function () {
    $("label[for='<%= @todo.id %>']").click(function () {
        el = $("#todo-container-<%= @todo.id %>");
        el.addClass('animated fadeOut');
        el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',
        function (e) {
            el.removeClass('animated fadeOut');
            el.remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Here I'm trying (in my complete.js.erb file) to on the label click (which checks the checkbox) add the animated and fadeOut classes to the container, and then remove the class as well as container element after it has faded.

Can anyone help me out? My code is only doing 1 of my 2 requirements

Comment: can you make fiddle or post some html too

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the "animationend" event listener:

```
el.addEventListener("animationend", function().. , false);
```

More information can be found here:

[W3Schools animationend Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_animationstart)

Comment: I believe it's included with animate.css `el.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend',` but this only seems to add / remove class and not remove it afterwards.

Comment: You can look at this source: http://osvaldas.info/examples/detecting-css-animation-transition-end-with-javascript/oncssanimationend.js